# vba repeating numbers next to each other

Tags: excel, vba, repeat

Okay so I have a variable sized array in Excel. Using vba I'd like to find if there are any repeating values, so values that are next to each other that are the same, not just in the whole column.

I know just in excel you could use an if statement, but how could you just spread that out to the whole sheet using for loops.

Im extremely novice to vba. This was my first attempt, it didn't work though and I don't know how to continue.

total is a value entered in by the user

```
ok = True
For j = 2 To 24
    For l =1 to total
        If ActiveCell.Offset(j, l).Select = ActiveCell.Offset(j + 5, l)
        And ActiveCell.Offset(j + 4, l) And ActiveCell.Offset(j + 3, l) 
        And ActiveCell.Offset(j + 2, l) And ActiveCell.Offset(j + 1, l) Then
            ok = False
        End if
    Next
Next
```

Comment: You want to check if there's a duplicate in the whole column, or just whether duplicate values are next to one another? What do you want to do if you find a duplicate? Just update the variable 'ok' to `False`?

Comment: You need to explain the problem more.  eg  Are you using the array to store the data held in an excel sheet by any chance?  When you say "so values that are next to each other " does next to include "cells" that are to the left right , above and below a cell.  When about diagonally above and right?

Comment: at the moment it looks like your 'if' statement is trying to match each cell with the 5 below it. is this what you're intending?

Comment: Just duplicates next to each other in a column. The data is coming from a machine collecting data automatically, if the same value is repeated over and over we need to know if something is wrong with the data collection device.

Comment: and yes the if statement is trying to see if the cell matches the 5 below it

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to flag rows that immediately repeat, just check the value in the row above to see if it's the same. If so, flag the column. For example:

```
With Range("B2:B24")
    .Formula = "=IF(A2=A1,""X"","""")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

This is how it would appear for the following dataset:

```
╔════════╦═══════╗
║ Col A  ║ Col B ║
╠════════╬═══════╣
║     17 ║       ║
║     44 ║       ║
║     44 ║ X     ║
║     44 ║ X     ║
║     15 ║       ║
║     93 ║       ║
║     93 ║ X     ║
║     16 ║       ║
╚════════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to check if there are duplicates next to one another in the column, the below will do what you're after.

```
Sub arrayDuplicateCheck()
    Dim arrValues() As Variant
    Dim lrow As Long, i As Long, ok As Boolean

    ok = False
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arrValues = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lrow, 1))

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrValues, 1) - 1
        If arrValues(i, 1) = arrValues(i + 1, 1) Then
            ok = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox (ok)
End Sub
```

This is currently checking values within column A, you will have to adjust the range which is assigned to the array if you wish to check a different column. The do this, update the `arrValues = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lrow, 1))` to the column number you want to evaluate. If you're changing the array column, you will need to update the `lrow` variable to the same column number.

For example, `arrValues = Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(lrow, 4))` would now create the array from `Column D`.

**Edit:** If you want to check if all 5 rows below match, then you can just change the `For` and `If` statement to this:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(arrValues, 1) - 5
    If arrValues(i, 1) = arrValues(i + 1, 1) _
    And arrValues(i, 1) = arrValues(i + 2, 1) _
    And arrValues(i, 1) = arrValues(i + 3, 1) _
    And arrValues(i, 1) = arrValues(i + 4, 1) _
    And arrValues(i, 1) = arrValues(i + 5, 1) Then
        ok = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```